# How to use lerna with dotenv package?

Tags: node.js, lerna, monorepo, dotenv

I have a monorepo managed using Lerna. I need to use multiple environment variables to start my web server. My npm script to start the server is:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev:start": "lerna run --parallel dev:start"
}
```

I am also trying to use `dotenv` package to load environment variables for `.env` file. Since, `dotenv` is purely development helper to set **env vars**, I have installed it as a `devDependency` of top `package.json`. `dotenv` utilizes node.js preload script like: `node -r dotenv/config server_script.js`.

But with Lerna, I can no longer invoke preload script. Is there any way to use `dotenv` with `lerna`? Or alternately, how to run preload scripts with lerna?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But with Lerna, I can no longer invoke preload script

That's not true. Lerna [allows you](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/master/commands/run) to pass arguments to the npm script. You just need to pass it with a pair of double dashes:

*packages/ServerPkg/package.json:*

```
"dev:start": "node foo.js"
```

*package.json*

```
"dev:start": "lerna run dev:start -- -- -r /path/to/dotenv"
```

Should execute:

```
node foo.js -r /path/to/dotenv
```

Comment: I think he wanted to pass that argument to `node` thouhg, not `foo.js`.  You can get around this by using something like `NODE_OPTIONS="-r dotenv/config"`